# Building a large home screen icon

Tags: android, icons, widget, homescreen

We're creating an app that will become the dedicated purpose for the phones it's installed on.  Towards this end, what's the best way to create a dedicated homescreen page for the app?  Is it possible to create an app with a large homescreen icon, or do we have to build a "widget"?

Answer (score 0):

This is, on the other hand, a dev question but it still is pretty practical, so I'll answer it here. The icons are pretty much standard sized in all the launchers, so there could be two other options: a widget or a background + icon.

Since the devices will be dedicated to the app, it's possible to design a background to suit the full screen size, but still emphasize the icon.

The other possibility is to create a widget with the sole purpose of launching the app, which requires a bit more work, but gives the possibility of enhancing the  home screen with additional features in the future with the codebase you already have.

Comment: if it is dedicated, couldn't it launch the intent on boot. And disable any actions that would cause the app to close? BTW, this is probably more suitable for StackOverflow.